# why can't I match programmatic pattern whose part is generated at runtime?

Tags: regex, perl

I have the latest Perl this time.  And this bombs

```
>perl -e '$pat = q(^).qr{(??{$_})}x; print /$pat/'
Eval-group not allowed at runtime, use re 'eval' in regex m/^(?^x:(??{$_}))/ at -e line 1.
```

Why, if any of these are fine:

```
>perl -e 'print /q(^).qr{(??{$_})}x/'

>perl -e '$pat = qr{(??{$_})}x; print /$pat/'

>perl -e '$pat = q(^).qr{$_}; print /$pat/'
```

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? Can you show some input data and the desired output?

Comment: Jonathan, this is not a good comment.  I gave you an SSCCE.  Please appreciate that.  That is always the best way.  Questioning "why are you doing this" is pointless.  Sorry.

Comment: Following ysth, adding `use re q(eval);` cures the problem.  As to why it is not needed in the other examples above, especially the first one, God only knows.  (God being Larry Wall that is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to what does a perl warning or error message mean always begins with consulting [perldoc perldiag](http://p3rl.org/perldiag), which says:

> (F) Perl tried to compile a regular expression containing the "(?{
>              ... })" zero-width assertion at run time, as it would when the
>              pattern contains interpolated values.  Since that is a security
>              risk, it is not allowed.  If you insist, you may still do this by
>              using the "re 'eval'" pragma or by explicitly building the pattern
>              from an interpolated string at run time and using that in an
>              eval().  See "(?{ code })" in perlre.

Since it's a potentially highly insecure operation, possibly directly running code entered as user input, you must explicitly enable it.

Comment: Thank you.  I did find out what the error message meant, but did not bother to study it, because of the similar constructs which I quoted that did not need re 'eval'.

Comment: Only the first one needs it because only the first one interpolates a string containing `(??{ })`. In all the others, it's part of a regex literal.

Comment: yes I thought of that at the beginning, but...   how about the third one, also interpolates a same thing, just without the additional q(^)